# Java: Weird gaps in jlabel text when setting

Tags: java, jlabel

I am making a questionaire app, every time you click next a title changes from "Question 1 of 10" to "Question 2 of 10".

But there is a weird graphical error. I am using netbeans and most of the code is generated for you. 
I change the text as follows:

```
 private void ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    currentScreen++;
    Header.setText(titles[currentScreen]);
}
```

The graphical error looks like this:
[image]
and that is for all text expect the the text I wrote into the jlabel in the beginning (in the netbeans design tab

Comment: I've never seen a JLabel do this.  Can you provide more code, so we can reproduce the problem ourselves?

Comment: I think it's an error in the install of the jre, the app looks normal on other computers and the java options app has the same glitch. Thanks though